# using variable declared in class file to include a control file

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

can we use variable declared in class file to include a control file

For Example, I have in class file of test.ascx

```
public string username= "test";
```

then in ascx I want it like:

```
< %@ Register TagPrefix="_test" TagName="usernametest" Src="~/portals/" + username + "/test.ascx" %>
```

This works fine If i user test instead of username here but like this throws error of

> Parser Error Message: The server block is not well formed.

Comment: And I know how to add a control from class file itself...just wanted to know if we can use it like I want here or Not

Comment: Try Src='<%= "~/portals/" + username + "/test.ascx" %>' (not sure it will work).

Comment: it won't ...asp tags already exist....Amiram

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the control programatically in the code behind:

```
        UserControl ctrl = new UserControl();
        ctrl.LoadControl("user/control/path.ascx");
        this.Page.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: Hi Razvan, I know this way.....wanted to know a way to add the way i am trying above.....but thanks